# ReactJs: TypeScript - Saving data on child component and displaying back to Parent Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript

ReactJs - I am building an application on TypeScript that holds 5 fields viz:-

1. UserName - String
2. Address - String
3. D.O.B
4. Hobbies - String
5. Postal Code - String

Component - 'UserDetails.tsx' consists of 5 input box where we will enter above details followed by 1 Submit button.

Now there is one 'ParentComponent.tsx' where i am importing above 'UserDetails'.

So on click of 1 button on 'ParentComponent' one dialog box is appearing holding above 5 details now I want to know on click of Submit how to save above 5 details and display those data back on 'ParentComponent'.

Specifically curious to know how to save list of several data(i guess in an array) on one component then displaying it back to its parent Component.

Building it on ReactJs - Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html to get basic idea of this and can make changes accordingly.

Anyone having specific answer to it please do comment